# How to use PowerShell's Invoke-WebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

PowerShell 3.0 offers a very decent new cmdlet called Invoke-WebRequest.
Is there a way to make use of its functionality using C# respectively .NET without invoking the cmdlet directly? Is it even based on .NET?

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 5):

You can use [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to do the same thing. you've got a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N) about that.

Comment: I know HttpWebRequest. However, Invoke-WebRequest returns elements of the requested web page as object (i.e. links, forms, input fields...).